# SVG + HTML in PDF (javascript or php)

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, svg

I am trying to put a HTML content with several svg (from Google Chart API) in a PDF. Is anyone know a simple way to do that ? (The solution can be in JavaScript or php)

I have tried with this https://github.com/WebbyLab/js-html-to-pdf
But this program allows to download only pdf in a single page, so I don't have the whole part of my html page.

Comment: What do you mean by "whole part of my html page"? Is there some part missing? Do you mean that PDF result is only first page where the document should have multiple pages?

Comment: Yes, I want to have multiple page in my PDF and with the link I use, my PDF has one page. I just want multiple page in my pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)

> Dompdf is an HTML to PDF converter

**Features**

- Handles most CSS 2.1 and a few CSS3 properties, including @import, @media & @page rules
- Supports most presentational HTML 4.0 attributes
- Supports external stylesheets, either local or through http/ftp (via fopen-wrappers)
- Supports complex tables, including row & column spans, separate & collapsed border models, individual cell styling
- Image support (gif, png (8, 24 and 32 bit with alpha channel), bmp & jpeg)
- No dependencies on external PDF libraries, thanks to the R&OS PDF class
- Inline PHP support
- **Basic SVG support**